# Are these climate zones somewhat realistic?

Tags: environment, earth-like, climate, geography

I have been slowly losing my mind trying to build a somewhat realistic climate map for a fantasy world I'm building for my book. A geographer I am not... I modeled the climate zones and such after this article: https://medium.com/universe-factory/climate-modeling-101-4544e00a2ff2

I've been staring at it for so long now that I've lost perspective, and would be really grateful for some feedback on if it makes sense or not.

Also, I realised I put a large river in a subtropical area (starting from the mountains right at the northern subtropical ridge). There is a country here and I was thinking of it kind of like the Nile with settlements around the river. Is it completely unrealistic for a large river to go through this area? Thankful for any and all help!

[image: Climate zone map]

I also made a rough map of the precipitation, where blue is more rain, dark blue is monsoon area, yellow is medium precipitation, and orange is drier. It's a bit of a rough map, but this wasn't explained too much in the article and was honestly losing patience by the time I got to this point of constructing this world. I tried reading some other resources on precipitation, but finding it a little hard to pin down.

[image: Precipitation map]

Feedback would be very appreciated. Thanks!

/Nora

EDIT

Do you mean something like this with changing the coasts? Is it reversed on the south hemisphere compared to the north since the winds go the other way? I left the arrows for the winds in, hope that these are right...

Is it just the precipitation map that is wrong, or was it the actual climate zones map as well? I did look into the Koppen classification a bit, but I'm not really looking at doing something that detailed, I just want to make sure the zones are believable/accurate.

Thanks for all your comments and help!

[image: Updated precipitation map]

Changed the climate map a little bit as well, mainly because I needed the desert climate to come down a little further on the continent to the right (next to the canyon), mainly for storytelling reasons. Does that look realistic? Thanks!

[image: Updated climate map]

EDIT 2:

So, I've tried doing the Koppen climate classifications and adding it to my map. So far I've only finished the right continent, but I thought I'd post it and see if it looks ok. The continent on the left is a WIP, I don't intend to leave that whole area as Cfa and Af, but the right continent is the most important one initially for my story, so I focused on that one.

[image]

Comment: I suggest you dig into the Koppen Climate Classification https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6ppen_climate_classification. Your coastal climates are not right. For instance on northern continents, the western coast is mild and wet if there is a mountain range. Think Seattle and Portland. Then dry on the other side of the mountains. The middle of continents are cold and hot. Obviously at the equator they will be more tropical.

Comment: @SteveS. that depends on the rotation of the planet. Does it spin in the same direction as Earth, or the other way round?

Comment: @DarthDonut Simple fix. Just switch coasts for those climates. Just as you would moving from northern to southern hemisphere

Comment: @DarthDonut, by definition east is the direction the planet spins toward, and if you look east the north is to your left, south to your right, and west behind you. If the planet rotates the other way, you make a 180 degree turn and...north is to your left, south to your right, and west is behind you. The map would simply be rotated 180 degrees as well.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for all your advice, I tried to make a few edits, does it look better? Is that what you meant? I tried looking into Koppen climate classifications a bit, but am not looking to make it that detailed really. I tried to switch the coasts like you said, but I read that it's reversed on the southern hemisphere because of the winds? Anyway, thanks for your help and I'd be grateful to hear if my last attempt is any better...

Comment: Oh and also, for the sake of simplicity I made the planet the same as Earth, just the landmasses are different

Answer (score 3):

A geographer, I am.  A graphics artist, I am not.

**Caveat: Climate and worldbuilding is enormously complex, so feel free to edit as you like: we don't even fully understand our own planet yet!**  And I will stress over and over that *your map is fine the way it is,* but since you asked..

Your map is not impossible, but there are going to be some changes needed to be a little more believable.  Considering your climate mock-up, recall that you will have very earth-like currents bringing warm water from the equator north to push cold water south.  This is why, for example, Tokyo is the same latitude as Los Angeles, but is much cooler – it gets the ‘cold’ water.  It’s also why Portugal reaches as far north as Maine, but is much, much warmer.

So let’s put in your currents and make one face warmer than the other and vice-versa.

[image]

Now, let’s look at your precipitation.  With these currents, you’re sending warm, tropical weather west in general, assuming a similar earthlike planet.

Let’s look at continent B, which will be exciting.  The only major change is that you’re going to have a crazy ‘waistline’ area – warm and wet meets cold and wet, cold and dry: thunderstorms, tornadoes and havoc all year round.

Your Nile is not unrealistic, but I'd posit that a more similar Nile can be found in the southwest quarter of Continent B.  Arid, and put your massive river running through.

Finally, your little island in the southwest will be receiving a lot of warm, humid air against a colder latitude.  This makes for a very bio-diverse region particularly as it's isolated from other major continents.  Have fun and be imaginative with your little Madagascar!

Comment: +1 for the fact that currents play a big part in climate. Geography, currents, star-planet interfacing (distance, angle, temp, etc.).

Comment: @KenLFG - yes, currents in a place (like Earth) that has an enormous amount of temperature-moderating forces (like Water) means wonderful climate implications.

Comment: I'm also operating under the assumption that the OP is American, otherwise I can change the descriptions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! It's really helpful for me to get input from someone who knows what they're talking about! It's really interesting what you're saying about the island to the southwest, because I had actually wanted to have a warm, humid, kind of tropical climate on that island but I thought that wouldn't be possible because of it's location. I even considered moving it higher up, but then that messed up the rest of my story so I just resigned myself to having a colder climate there, which I now don't need to do, so that's great!

Comment: When you're saying continent B, I assume you mean the one on the right? What would cause this whole area to have a crazy tropical weather? I had thought that this area would be like grasslands along the top transitioning to a desert further south and then a wet/dry savannah like climate. I did think that the east coast along that 'waistline area' would have thunderstorms and tornadoes, kind of like Florida, but I hadn't considered that this would extend from coast to coast.

Comment: I've actually tried to add Koppen climate classifications to my map, I'll edit my question and add it if you want to have a look! Also I'm actually Swedish, but don't worry I do know the basic geography of USA so I completely understand your comparisons, and they're really helpful!

Comment: @NoraR - I've spent much of my life in Sweden, but glad you know the micro-climates - interestingly I've recently learned that NW France is one of the only other places in the world with the exact climate of Portland/Seattle, and mushroom truffles will only grow in those two locations.  (until things change)

Comment: Also, question about the currents: I thought that the ocean currents went clockwise in the northern hemisphere and counter clockwise in the southern hemisphere? I realise that's over simplifying things, but when I was trying to work out my climate that's the basic idea I got from what I was reading.

Comment: @NoraR - your world is different :)

Comment: Really, you've lived in Sweden? That's pretty cool, were you working here?

Comment: @Nora you’re correct about the oceanic circulation patterns - since your climatic cells match those of Earth and the Coriolis force is the same (deflecting to the right in the northern hemisphere, left in the southern) the gyres should be clockwise in the northern hemisphere and counter in the southern. Not sure why Mikey thinks your world is different.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, this is actually really accurate, assuming that the planet is the size of earth, or something similar. I like the touch of monsoon as well.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding!  Could you add a bit more explanation about how you know this is accurate, so others can follow and learn from your thought process?  Thanks.  You can [edit] your answer to add more details.

Comment: Thank you! I got some comments that my coasts were wrong, so I added an edit where I changed a few things, do you think it's more accurate that way? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So, no hard science from my side, but I'm really interested in this topic, so I gathered some knowledge on this. Most of the map is really accurate, and i like how you took the mountains in account for desertification. There are two things that aren't that likely to occur (but still possible):
The river on southern part of the continent on the right. They mountains would cause most of the rain to fall on their western side, which would make a river flowing east less likely. But this depends on the formation on the Mountains, it could still be possible that the rain falling west and on top of the mountains feeds a river eastwards. If that's relevant (and important) for you, you should maybe describe this area. (Similarity to Earth: [Atacama Desert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atacama_Desert))
The second thing i would like to point out is way up in the north of the right continent. I suspect the area east of the Mountains a total wasteland. Similar to the [Gobi Desert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gobi_Desert), it's far into the continent and shielded by mountains. I guess this would be very cold, harsh and dry lands. (This is only a possibility, not a fact, as this is a fictional world. Some streams of air and such things could behave slightly differently, leading to a different climate.)